# How to write two different dtypes in the same file?

Tags: python, numpy

I have written the following array in a binary file.

```
np.asfortranarray([[x.T],
                    [y.T],
                    [z.T]], dtype='f4').tofile('grid.dat')
```

Now, I want to add four values of dtype 'i4' (1,720,152,129) above this array in such a way that when grid.dat file is read using `np.fromfile(file, dtype="i4", count=4)`, user should get these values.

Comment: a numpy array can only have one dtype.

Comment: Can't we add another numpy array of a different dtype in the same file as a separate array?

Comment: You can put whatever you want in a file. But if you want to use the basic numpy I/O functions it's one array per file.

Comment: Is there another way to input these values in the same file without using numpy I/O functions but still with dtype i4? I tried FortranFile from scipy.io, but these values are getting overwritten.

Comment: `tofile` takes an open file as argument.  So you could write several different arrays to one file.  `fromfile` can  also use a file, but needs the correct count and dtype for each segment.

Comment: Look at pickle maybe? You can pickle a tuple of arrays...